# map: is there any way we can add keys to an array which is based on its values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following Map:

```
'1st key' => [{'name': 'apple'}, {'other': 'orange'}],
'2nd key' => [{'name': 'mango'}, {'other': 'lemon'}]
```

I want to cenvert this map to a new array and also add keys.

`Array.from(map.values())` converts values to array, es expected, but I want to add keys as attributes...

Expected result:

```
 [ {'id': '1st key'}, {'name': 'apple'}, {'other': 'orange'}]
 [ {'id': '2nd key'}, {'name': 'mango'}, {'other': 'lemon'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map.entries()` so you get the keys and values. Then you can insert the key at the beginning of the value array.

```
Array.from(map.entries()).map(([key, val]) => [{id: key}, ...val]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the right direction  Array.from(map).map(([key, val]) => [{id: key}, ...val])